# ANOVA in R using summary data

Tags: r, summary, lm, anova

is it possible to run an ANOVA in r with only means, standard deviation and n-value? Here is my data frame:

```
q2data.mean <- c(90,85,92,100,102,106)
q2data.sd <- c(9.035613,11.479667,9.760268,7.662572,9.830258,9.111457)
q2data.n <- c(9,9,9,9,9,9)
q2data.frame <- data.frame(q2data.mean,q2data.sq,q2data.n)
```

I am trying to find the means square residual, so I want to take a look at the ANOVA table.

Any help would be really appreciated! :)

Comment: Also, searching google for your exact title of this question gives a link to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95949/one-way-anova-from-summary-data-in-r which points you to: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rpsychi/docs/ind.oneway.second

Answer (score 9):

Here you go, using `ind.oneway.second` from the `rspychi` package:

```
library(rpsychi)
with(q2data.frame, ind.oneway.second(q2data.mean,q2data.sd,q2data.n) )

#$anova.table
#                SS df     MS     F
#Between (A) 2923.5  5 584.70 6.413
#Within      4376.4 48  91.18      
#Total       7299.9 53   
# etc etc
```

***Update***: the rpsychi package was archived in March 2022 but the function is still available here: http://github.com/cran/rpsychi/blob/master/R/ind.oneway.second.R (hat-tip to [@jrcalabrese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14992857/jrcalabrese) in the comments)

---

As an unrelated side note, your data could do with some renaming. `q2data.frame` is a `data.frame`, no need to put it in the title. Also, no need to specify `q2data.mean` inside `q2data.frame` - surely `mean` would suffice. It just means you end up with complex code like:

```
q2data.frame$q2data.mean
```

when:

```
q2$mean
```

would give you all the info you need.

Comment: You are a godsend, thank you! Also: for those without the rpsychi library included the following code before the above script: install.packages("rpsychi")

install.packages("gtools")

Comment: @BrettCochrane - `install.packages` should handle getting all the dependencies - no need to install gtools separately.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `rpsychi` package was archived in March 2022 but the function is still available here: https://github.com/cran/rpsychi/blob/master/R/ind.oneway.second.R